# catch touch event on blackberry api5

Tags: events, blackberry

I want to catch the touch event in OS5. I use this method `protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message)` in ListFieldRich. But this method didn't run it. I press all keys nothing happens. Even if I debug my code, this method didn't run when press keys.
How can I know the touch event in OS5?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem. I used this method  `protected boolean trackwheelClick(int status, int time)`

Answer (score 2):

Touchevent will be called if you have a touch screen phone, and you touch the screen. It will not be called if you press the keys or buttons. Did you touch the screen?

Answer (score 1):

`setChangeListener()` on your `RichTextField` and override these method in your `Screen` class

```java
     protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
         if(Touchscreen.isSupported()) {
             return false;
         }
         fieldChangeNotify(1);
         return true;
     }

     //for  touch

     protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent message) {            
         if (TouchEvent.CLICK == message.getEvent()) {              
             FieldChangeListener listener = getChangeListener();                
             if (null != listener)                     
                 listener.fieldChanged(this, 1);           
         }           
         return super.touchEvent(message);         
     }
```

and in `fieldChanged()` method

```java
public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {

    if (field == yourRichTextField) {
        Dialog.inform("RichtextField Clicked Button Pressed");
    }
```